# oo uml modelling breakout relationship

Tags: oop, uml

Hi I'm preparing for interview tech test and one of the things is to model a scenario with uml class diagram. I've no idea what a breakout relationship is. Has anyone any information to help me?

Comment: https://creately.com/diagram/example/hdfty5vy/Breakout%20UML%20Class%20Diagram

Comment: So the answer is: it's the Breakout Game?

Comment: OOP and class diagrams are for systems modeling, not for data modeling.